# Ran Analyzer : Potential Memory Leak

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks

[image]

Hi,

I ran the XCode analyser - and it tells me that the following both are potential memory leaks. 
I'm not sure why. 
I declared midiDevices like this

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* midiDevices;
```

Here's the code for openMidiIn

```
-(void)openMidiIn {
    int k, endpoints;

    CFStringRef name = NULL, cname = NULL, pname = NULL;
    CFStringEncoding defaultEncoding = CFStringGetSystemEncoding();
    MIDIPortRef mport = NULL;
    MIDIEndpointRef endpoint;
    OSStatus ret;

    /* MIDI client */
    cname = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "my client", defaultEncoding);
    ret = MIDIClientCreate(cname, NULL, NULL, &mclient);
    if(!ret){
        /* MIDI output port */
        pname = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "outport", defaultEncoding);
        ret = MIDIInputPortCreate(mclient, pname, MidiWidgetsManagerReadProc, self, &mport);
        if(!ret){
            /* sources, we connect to all available input sources */
            endpoints = MIDIGetNumberOfSources();
            //NSLog(@"midi srcs %d\n", endpoints);
            for(k=0; k < endpoints; k++){
                endpoint = MIDIGetSource(k);
                void *srcRefCon = endpoint;
                MIDIPortConnectSource(mport, endpoint, srcRefCon);

            }
        }
    }
    if(name) CFRelease(name);
    if(pname) CFRelease(pname);
    if(cname) CFRelease(cname);

}
```

Thanks for your help.

---

analyzer info
Here's more info about the error about making a bit of changes.

[image]

Comment: you need to read about memory management and properties in Objective-C. In short, you can't use `assign` for an class-type property and expect that to work.

Comment: A property with assign shouldn't be allocated, instead have a value assigned to it => midiDevices = otherArray. Use retain / strong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using ARC, that object will actually be released and dealloc'd instantly. Why it's saying you have a memory leak is confusing, but you will have a dead reference. Use `strong`, not `assign`.

Comment: I"m not using ARC.. this project has to be non-ARC. I'll try it out.

Comment: OK, then use `retain` and `self.midiDevices = [NSMutableArray array];`

Comment: I set it to retain, nonatomic and did self.midiDevices = [NSMutableArray array]; I still get the potential leak warning in blue.

Comment: Show us the code for `openMidiIn` - the problem's probably in there.

Comment: Could it be that it wants you to release `mport`? I'm just guessing here, I've never played with the MIDI code. The analyzer should actually tell you specifically what and how the leak might occur.

Comment: I pasted more info about the potential memory leak. Hopefully it'll help.

Comment: It's `motionManager`. You need to write `self.motionManager = [[[CMMotionManager alloc] init] autorelease];`

Comment: Ah yes that's it. Thanks so much Guy. I really gotta go read up on memory stuff like the rest of the posts have suggested, but I was in a rush. Thanks!